# How do I return a value from a function in python that has an exception if it fails

Tags: function, python-2.7, error-handling

I would like to have a check when a user enters certain values. For example if a user enters a value that is outside the range from 250-10000 then it should show a message warning them that they have entered a bad value and to renter that value. The code I have works if they enter a correct value. If they enter an incorrect value they get a message but now if they enter the correct value how do I get it back to fc in main(). I am open to any positive feedback!. Thanks for your help in advance!

```
import ctypes


def build_fc():
    print "Please enter fc between 250-10000:"
    fc_string_input = raw_input()
    fc_float = float(fc_string_input)
    if (fc_float)>=250 and (fc_float<=10000):
         return float(fc_string_input)
    else:
         setup_fc_error_message()
         build_fc()

def setup_fc_error_message():
    lines = ['fc is out of range: Please Enter a value from 250-10000:']
    MessageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA
    MessageBox(None, "\n".join(lines), 'Setup Info', 0) 

def main():

    fc = build_fc()
    print fc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of,

```
else:
   setup_fc_error_message()
   build_fc()
```

Try:

```
else:
   setup_fc_error_message()
   return build_fc()
```

Comment: Please consider upvoting/marking this as answer by clicking on the 'tick' on the left if it solved your problem. Thanks.